# JPA Having multiple Lists of the same entity

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish, persistence, entities

Im learning JPA and I have an entity class named User that has two lists of another entity, Car, but i cant get it to work with jpa.
The classes have all the getters, setters and constructors needed.

This is my User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String userName;     

    @OneToMany(i dont know what goes here as well)
    private List<Car> owned;

    @OneToMany( ?? )
    private List<Car> rented;
```

This is my Car class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Cars")
public class Car implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;    

    @ManyToOne ( ?? ) 
    private User owner;
```

My two questions would be:

1. What annotations go to each @Something to make this work?
2. After i have all set up, how would i add a new car to an existing user and persist it as well?

Thank you!

Comment: How does your table named `Users`, `Cars` look like? Do you have any table which acts as a `JoinTable` between them?

Comment: Sorry i didnt add that. My tables are like this:
**Users**: Id(PK), Username(UK)
**Cars**: Id(PK), Owner_Id()
**Users_Cars**: userId, rented, owned

Comment: Kindly put the sql structure of your database tables.

Comment: Shouldnt i just add the correct annotations and let the tables be generated correctly by jpa? @SanjeevSaha